# How can I completely remove the label of SetterBar in Manipulate[...]?

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

For example, I have the bellow code:

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[invert*Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}],
  {{invert, 1}, {1 -> "reset", -1 -> "invert"}}
]
```

Even though I set the label of `SetterBar` as `Null`, (refering the bellow codes), there is still a small blank.

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[invert*Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}],
  {{invert, 1, Null}, {1 -> "reset", -1 -> "invert"}}
]
```

How can I remove the label within red circle, no blank left, i.e. "reset" laid left most.

[image]

Comment: That's weird, I'm not seeing a label on Mathematica 11.2. What version are you using?

Comment: notice there is a margin for a label too, if you want precise control, use `DynamicModule+ Column` etc.

Comment: @numbermaniac My platform is also Mathematica 11.2 on Windows 10. There do be some margin (please refer to my post bellow).

Comment: @Kuba Thanks, I have worked out a solution following your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how to do it using `Manipulate`'s shortcut control specification, but I can show you how to do it by specifying the setter bar in full control form.

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[invert*Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}],
  Framed[
    Control[{{invert, 1, ""}, {1 -> "reset", -1 -> "invert"}}],
    FrameMargins -> {{-12, 0}, {0, 0}},
    FrameStyle -> Transparent]]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: I worked out a solution following advice from @Kuba . But your new answer is still better than mine. ^_^ '''' It's more precise.

Comment: @PureLine. I didn't give you any advice. It was Kuba who gave advice.

Comment: I've corrected it. 囧rz.... @m_goldberg

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for @Kuba. I think I have made it.

Firstly, I will show my previous solution with `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[ (* Note: I use Null to delete the label *)
  Plot[invert*Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}], {{invert, 1, Null}, {1 -> "reset", -1 -> "invert"}, 
  Appearance -> "Vertical"}, ContentSize -> {360, 240}]
```

Above codes output:

[image]

Following @Kuba 's suggestion, I crafted my codes as following:

```
DynamicModule[{invert = 1}, 
  Framed@Column[{Dynamic[invert], {1 -> "Reset", -1 -> "Invert"}, Appearance -> "Vertical"], 
     Framed[Dynamic[Plot[invert*Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, ImageSize -> {360, 240}]], 
       FrameStyle -> Gray]}]]
```

Which produced:

[image]

Apparently, the first one generated by `Manipulate` has some blank space before **reset** button. And `DynamicModule` can eliminate the margin.